# How can I drag and drop a tile(image) into a specified place? WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, user-interface

I am creating a Map Editor for my game using WPF Forms.
I have one problem though. How can I drag and drop a tile(image) into a specified place?

I'll try to detail my need. Take for instance this image:

[image]

So what I want is that every tile - will be selected by the user and dragged to the grid area - is "attracted" to a cell. Is that clear?
That way the user would see every tile in its place.

Does anyone know how to implement that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I am not entirely sure if you are asking for "How to implement Drag&Drop?" or "How to prevent the user from dropping anywhere but within a specified location?", so I try to give some clues about both.

**How to implement Drag&Drop?**

To get basic drag&drop funcionality you would do something like this:

- Set the AllowDrop property of your desired drag target to true.
- Hook up for OnMouseMove and MouseLeftButtonDown to be able to detect the start of a D&D operation. (this events are in System.Windows.UIElement)
- Hook up for OnPreviewDragEnter, OnPreviewDragLeave, OnPreviewDragOver, OnPreviewDrop (this events are in System.Windows.DragDrop)
- Then you listen for OnMouseMove and MouseLeftButtonDown until the user initializes a drag operation (i.e. moved either SystemParameters.MinimumHorizontalDragDistance or SystemParameters.MinimumVerticalDragDistance wide while left mouse button was pressed)
- At this point you will have to initialize a D&D operation with DragDrop.DoDragDrop
- After the initialization you would listen for all the drag events listed above, but to get the basic functionality it is enough to listen for the OnPreviewDrop.

**How to prevent the user from dropping anywhere but within a specified location?**

After you have implemented the D&D functionality it is pretty straightforward to achieve this. Just check if the sender of OnPreviewDrop is the currently active drop target and ignore the drop event if it's not.

**More**

To find more detailed informations you should visit this [Drag and Drop Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742859.aspx).
Since it is a game you would probably like to display the dragged content while dragging, you can achieve this with [adorners](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743737.aspx). The provided example does not cover enough to get the preview of a dragged image displayed but google lists many good examples on the topic.